# Printing the arbitrary address of a not initialized pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I found that, in order to print the arbitrary address of a **not initialized** pointer the code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int x = 1;
int *pi0;
int *pi = NULL;
int *pi2 = &x;
int *pi3;
int **ppi;

    printf("Indirizzo pi0: \t %p\n", pi0);      // 0x55e43192a080
    printf("Indirizzo pi: \t %p\n", pi);        // (nil)
    printf("Indirizzo x: \t %p\n", &x);         // 0x7ffdb8405f44
    printf("Indirizzo pi2: \t %p\n", pi2);      // 0x7ffdb8405f44
    printf("Indirizzo pi3: \t %p\n", pi3);      // 0x7ffe56ffe6b0
    printf("Indirizzo pi3: \t %p\n", ppi);      // ???
    
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to do the same with a **not initialized** pointer to pointer, but, as you can see in the last printf, if I try to print the address of ppi, nothing happens (no warning, no error, no output).

---

EDIT: the code works, I did a mistake in the last printf because I wrote pi3 instead of ppi.

Comment: Using uninitialized variables (pointers including) is UB. Usually uninitialized variables get random garbage from memory as value.

Comment: I get `0x0` for the last one.

Comment: I get `0x0` for all the uninitialized pointers.

Comment: Also can't reproduce, I get a random address for the last one.

Comment: Change the text to `"Indirizzo ppi"`

Comment: But as @Jorengarenar said, using uninitialized variables results in undefined behavior. There's no reason to expect it to print the arbitrary value.

Comment: thank you to all of you, I did a mistake in the printf: I wrote pi3 instead of ppi and this confused me. I apologize for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Basically anything that happens here is dependent on your system's underlying implementation. You are invoking undefined behavior by accessing the value of an uninitialized variable (in this case a pointer, which is a variable that holds a virtual memory address).

If your system doesn't notice or doesn't care it'll probably just print out the value of the register the compiler is using for ppi, which is probably 0x0 (nil) or maybe a completely arbitrary value.

Undefined behavior does not mean that there will be an error message or the program will crash or anything at all, it simply means that the C programming language does not guarantee any specific behavior, so whatever the compiler decides to do is completely valid. [This](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) is a good read if you want to learn more